# What version Apache is installed where?

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl

We are trying to get https working on Apache.  It's located at /usr/local/apache2/bin

I can run `/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl start` if https is not used.

However, if I uncomment this line in httpd.conf:

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

Then `/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl start` doesn't work.  It keeps giving me an error

```
# /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl start
Syntax error on line 56 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:
Invalid command 'SSLPassPhraseDialog', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

The line in httpd-ssl.conf is

```
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
```

We also have httpd installed at /usr/sbin/.  The tomcat at this location runs fine when I uncomment the above line.  Both are running version 2.2.15, just off by like 3 months (which I guess makes the difference).

```
# /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Jul 17 2017 13:25:42

# /usr/sbin/httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Mar 22 2017 06:52:55
```

Does anyone know why this is happening in /usr/local/apache2/bin and not /usr/sbin/ or know how to solve this syntax error?  The workaround I'm doing now is to use /usr/sbin but I would like to know the cause of this in case I run into it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

> What version Apache is installed where?

```
# which -a apache2
/usr/sbin/apache2
# which -a httpd
/usr/sbin/httpd
```

assuming it's on your $PATH

> ...how to solve this syntax error?

As noted in the help/man you can (and should) use a different config for each version;

```
/usr/sbin/httpd -h 2>&1 | grep ServerConfigFile
  -f file            : specify an alternate ServerConfigFile
```

> ...SSLPassPhraseDialog...

You can "list available configuration directives" with

```
/usr/sbin/httpd -L | grep -A 2 SSLPassPhraseDialog
SSLPassPhraseDialog (mod_ssl.c)
    SSL dialog mechanism for the pass phrase query ('builtin', '|/path/to/pipe_program', or 'exec:/path/to/cgi_program')
    Allowed in *.conf only outside <Directory>, <Files>, <Location>, or <If>
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  For me, apache2 is not an executable but a directory in /usr/local/apache2/bin/.  There is no apache2 in /usr/sbin either, just /usr/sbin/apachectl , which is what I used to start it up  =(  Regarding the apache2 -L | grep -A SSLPassPhraseDialog, nothing shows up when I run it  in both locations  =(   I still upvoted since you threw some new things at me to try

Comment: @Classified On your system apache2 is called httpd so just substitute (Fedora vs Debian based systems)